# How to Send WhatsApp Messages from Excel: Send Image

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I use the following VBA code to send WhatsApp messages from Excel. It uses Selenium and Chrome Driver. This code works fine for sending text-only messages. What I need to do is to send a screenshot of a range of cells. In Excel when you copy a range, for example A1:D5, and paste that range into WhatsApp, a screenshot is pasted. How should I get that **screenshot** sent, in other words, how to send an **image**? Doing only in VBA

My Code(VBA):

```
Sub WebWhatsApp()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim ks As New Keys

bot.Start "chrome", "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
bot.Get "/"

MsgBox "Please scan code, then press OK"

'Get search text(phone number or name) from worksheet
searchtext = Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value

'Get textmessage from worksheet
textmessage = "This is a text message."

'click in the search box
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='side']/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]").Click

'wait 500 ms
bot.Wait (500)

'Insert search text(phone number or name)
bot.SendKeys (searchtext)

'wait 500 ms
bot.Wait (500)

'Insert search text(phone number or name)
bot.SendKeys (ks.Enter)

'wait 500 ms
bot.Wait (500)

'Load message into WebWhatsApp
bot.SendKeys (textmessage)

'wait 500 ms
bot.Wait (500)

'press enter to send the message
bot.SendKeys (ks.Enter)

Stop


End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried to send an image? [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). • Maybe you should use the [WhatsApp Business API](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api) instead of very unstable `.SendKeys`.